# Turning off Content Approval for an entire site collection - Once

Tags: publishing-site, site-collection, content-approval

I'd like to turn off Content Approval, for all libraries, (Page, Document, Images) once, at a Site Collection level and, hopefully, it will be automatically set across the entire site collection. Having it off helps during the development of a Publishing Site. Once all the content/web parts are in then it would be good to turn it back on before going to UAT/Prod. Having approval workflows start in dev is just a waste of time.

I'm working in SP2010, but MOSS 2007 is still relevant as I have sites in both platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is a great idea, but I expect that you could do it either with the object model or with the SharePoint Web Services.  For the latter, take a look at my [jQuery Library for SharePoint Web Services (SPServies)](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

Either way, you'd need to loop through all of the sites and lists, changing the property settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response Marc. Yes I could loop through the site collection modifying the .EnableModeration to false. What I ended up doing is just deactivating the Approval Workdflow whilst I was entering content. Brutal but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out ...It might help you

http://waitingimpatiently.com/index.php/2008/11/11/41/